# Is formsflow.ai being affected by log4shell vulnerability?

Tags: formsflow.ai, formsflow

Formsflow.ai is using Camunda, which is a java based application. So will formsflow.ai be affected by the latest log4shell vulnerability which is a very high risk vulnerability with CVE-2021-44228.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, formsflow.ai is not using log4j-core in the dependency stack. It uses only the following dependencies

```
BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-to-slf4j-2.13.3.jar
BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.13.3.jar
```